# Unable to Plot a C.T. Signal Graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot the C.T. Signal Gaph (x(t)) in MATLAB for 0<=t<0.2 ms as mentioned in the below given figure. I have written the following code, but, not sure what should be the step size for time t in the graph. Any help would be highly appreciated:) Thanks!

```
t = 0:0.00002:0.0002;
f = 10000;
x = 4*sin(2*pi*f*t);
figure;
plot(t,x);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a misstatement in the text.  Ts is the sampling *period*, whereas the sampling *rate* is the inverse of the sampling period, Fs=1/Ts.  With a Ts of 0.02 ms, that means the sampling rate is actually 50 kHz.

What's happening in the graph is that a continuous function, x(t) is being sampled by multiplying it with a pulse train, p(t).  The p(t) function is composed of an infinite number of (Dirac) delta functions equally spaced by Ts seconds and goes on for infinity.  The input also goes on for forever, since sin(t) is defined for all t.  The concept here is to understand that by multiplying x(t) by p(t), you're getting samples of x(t) spaced out at Ts intervals.

Because both signals are infinite, you should just pick a meaningful time range for the analysis you wish to perform.  In this case, it's educational, so just pick maybe a few cycles of the incoming frequency so you can see the samples.  At 10kHz, the input should repeat every 0.1 ms.  You should expect to see 5 samples per cycle of the sine wave (0.1 ms / (0.02 ms/sample) = 5 samples).  I'd just plot it from -0.2 ms to 0.2 ms to see a few of the cycles.  By adding '-o' as the plot option, you'll see 'o' markers wherever the samples were taken.

```
t = -0.0002:0.00002:0.0002;
f = 10000;
x = 4*sin(2*pi*f*t);
figure;
plot(t,x,'-o');
```

You can try changing the sampling period.  For instance, try dividing it by 10.

```
t = -0.0002:0.000002:0.0002;
f = 10000;
x = 4*sin(2*pi*f*t);
figure;
plot(t,x,'-o');
```